# How do I log off from Stack Exchange network from a distance?

Tags: support, login, logout

I have used my S.E. account on computers in different locations, which might have kept my logins in their cache.

I would like to log out on all other devices but my own devices, preferably without having to reset my password.

**Can this be done?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a Stack Exchange account, just click on the logout link in the Stack Exchange dropdown in the top left corner of the page:

> [image]

You'll see the following dialog, make sure to check the "log out on all devices" option:

> [image]

If you're using Google, Facebook or any other external account, make sure you read the small print on that screenshot carefully. SE doesn't log you out of those, you have to do that yourself.

I actually had to check how it works, it's complicated enough (and has changed over time) that I just don't trust that I'll get it right, so I simply use incognito sessions on every computer that isn't my own. That way I don't have to understand how SE handles logout, I will always be logged out because the browser sessions doesn't remember anything by design. I recommend you do the same on untrusted devices.

Comment: This is different in my UI: http://imgur.com/a/WTRdb

Comment: @fabriced click on that link, and you'll end up on the page I showed in the screenshot

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Can you please edit your answer to reflect that first step? (just use my screencap in the comments) Thanks!